# Symfony session получить в другой системе

Tags: сессия, symfony

Всем привет, нужен совет (пример) как можно создать сессию в Symfony. Точнее, как создать я знаю, и получить её в другой системе не Symfony.

```
$session = new Session();
$session->setName('login');

$session->start();
$session->set('name', $user->getName());
```

После всех операций я делаю redirect в другое приложение не symfony и хочу получить эту сессию в $_SESSION возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1):

Сначала решите, к чему имеют доступ обе системы - например, общая файловая система. Если предполагается масштабирование, посмотрите в сторону Memcache, MongoDB или MySQL.

Symfony использует компонент `HttpFoundation`, который содержит классы для работы со всеми ими:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html
Если нужно что-то экзотическое, можно написать свой класс, который реализует `SessionHandlerInterface`

Если в другой системе вы также можете использовать `HttpFoundation`, то просто настройте их одинаково.

Если не можете использовать `HttpFoundation`, и:

- используете файлы, то настройте `session.save_path`, `session.name`, `session.save_handler` так же, как в Symfony:
  http://php.net/ru/session.configuration
- используете memcache, PDO или что-то ещё - напишите или найдите подходящий пользовательский обработчик сессии
  http://php.net/manual/ru/session.customhandler.php